# How to make Body move in Straight line in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I just started using libgdx and am having problem in moving body in straight line and want to turn in right direction by some angle on `touchDown`.

```
 //BALL  creating ball
    // body defination
    BodyDef  bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;   
    bodyDef.position.set(8.50f, 8.50f);


    //ball shape
    CircleShape ballshape = new CircleShape();
    ballshape.setRadius(.75f);


    // ball fixture defination
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = ballshape ;
    fixtureDef.density = 2.5f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.25f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.25f;

     ball = world.createBody(bodyDef);
     ball.createFixture(fixtureDef);

    ballshape.dispose();
```

I am trying to figure this out from 2 days, but can't find any example or tutorial anywhere. In every tutorial, people are using keyboard keys for the movement of the body & that is not working in android.

Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT :**
After trying little more last night, i came to know `touchDown` method is being called on touch.

```
 Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputController() {

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            ((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MainMenu());

         //  ball.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0,500), ball.getPosition() , true);
            return true;
        }


    });
```

as it is setting screen to MainMenu on touch, but its not working for any `force`,`impluse`or `velocity`.

Comment: where do you want to move the body to? Is it to where it is mouse touched or what? It is unclear what you want to achieve. Give more info

Comment: I want body to move parallel to y-axis, and and ontouch i want it to turn right by 25 degree.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some simple code which you can start with to move a body in Libgdx/Box2D
of course there is plenty way to do that here is a simple one :

> algo :
>
> if you touch the first half of the screen ==> body move
> backward
>
> if you touch the scond half of the screen ==> body move
> forward

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) { // Detect is finger on the screen
    int x = Gdx.input.getX(); // get x touch coordination
    int y = Gdx.input.getY(); // get y touch coordination
    
    if(x < Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2) { // First half Screen ==> move backward
        body.setLinearVelocity(-SpeedMove,0);
    }else if(x >= Gdx.graphics.getHeight() /2) { // Second half Screen ==> move forward
        body.setLinearVelocity(SpeedMove,0);
    }
}else { // no finger is on the screen
    body.setLinearVelocity(0,0); // ==> no moving body
}
```

any trouble leave a comment

Good luck !

Comment: First of all it's not working, i have tried this type of code in  'render' function. can you tell in which function i should do this

Comment: Yes this code go in the Render() , what do you mean it's not working : body not moving, you got errors , .... what speedMove value did you put did you try change the value.

Comment: Yes body is not moving at all,  I have tried to add different values like (5f,0) , (15.40f, 10f) , (10f,10f). But the result is same as before

Comment: could you put the code of when you use world.step() fucntion and debugRender.render() inside the render() function cause maybe the problem is related to that